# Java - Manual object validation against a white list

Tags: java, validation, object-comparison

I'm trying to write a class to take a mega object, and ensure that only certain fields have been changed, normally you would annotate / add validation this way, but that is not an option in this case unfortunately, the only thing I can change is the one class I am working on, which will receive the very large (and very nested!) object that I'm supposed to somehow validate.

My initial thoughts was to make a 'list' of things that can be changed, then iterate over all properties in the object and check if anything has been updated that is not on the 'whitelist', I have the old version of the object, so  I can check each field against the old one to confirm, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this, or if there is a better solution. I've never tried something like this before.

Any suggestions are appreciated. If there aren't any better solutions, how should I create the white list / iterate over all properties / nested properties of the mega object?

**UPDATE:**
Based on the suggestions, here is what I'm trying out, it still have a few problems though (Please note I'm just throwing things around, this is by no means my final class or good programming yet):

1. isTraversable works on collections, but I'm not sure how to get check custom classes, eg. a Person class, which would still need to be iterated through.
2. There are cyclic refs all over the place, not sure how to handle those either.

```
public class Test {
       private Object obj1;
       private Object obj2;
       private List<String> whitelist;

        public void validate(Object objectToTraverse, 
                             Object objectToCompareTo, 
                             List<String> whitelist){
            this.obj1 = objectToTraverse;
            this.obj2 = objectToCompareTo;
            this.whitelist = whitelist;

            traverseAndCompare(obj1, obj2);
        }

        private void traverseAndCompare(Object objectToTraverse, 
                                        Object objectToCompareTo){
            try {
                for (Field field : objectToTraverse.getClass()
                        .getDeclaredFields()) {

                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object fieldValue = field.get(objectToTraverse);

                    if (isTraversable(field)) {
                        traverseAndCompare(field.get(objectToTraverse), 
                                field.get(objectToCompareTo));
                    } else {
                        getFieldValuesAndCompare(field, obj1, obj2);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private boolean getFieldValuesAndCompare(Field field, 
                                                 Object obj1, 
                                                 Object obj2) 
                throws Exception{

            Object value1 = field.get(obj1);
            Object value2 = field.get(obj2);

            return compare(value1, value2);
        }

        private boolean compare(Object value1, 
                                Object value2){
            return Objects.equals(value1, value2);
        }

        private boolean isTraversable(Field field){
            // This should handle collections, but it does not work 
            // on custom classes, eg. Person class
            if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                return true;
            }

            // Need to somehow figure out is this is a class with 
            // properties I can traverse, or something with a value, 
            // like String, Long, etc, hopefully
            // without listing everything

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you care about *what* has changed, or only *whether* something has changed?

Comment: toString()? hashcode()?

Comment: I don't care about the what, only to make sure that nothing but properties x,y,z have changed, if anything else did, I'll throw an error :D. This is for an api end point where they are allowed to change certain fields.

Comment: What about a custom `Comparator` for the class? You can just compare the fields which are *not* allowed to change. Then, when calling this `Comparator`, if the result is not `0` you know an invalid field changed and return an error.

Comment: can you post sample model? comparing against primary fields/objects may be easy but if you have to compare if custom pojo A (which may have multiple primary fields) is changed or not then it is complicated and will need different solution.

Comment: I don't have a single model, this is a mixed object with hundreds of fields created from dozens of models. Also, I wouldn't be able to due to a contact :D. It's created from some Jaxb objects so I can't change the actual classes either.

Comment: **Not sure if this is the best suggestion.** If you can use third party library in your case, you can use `jackson-databind` to convert the source and target objects to JSON and compare the JSON data. You can use Jackson's MixIn feature to exclude the fields that you don't care about.

Comment: This may work, I think we use it elsewhere already, how do I go about doing this? Simply comparing the two doesn't do anything, without actually checking which fields changed and if they are allowed to or not.

Comment: @Ramu  this works if object size is small. In general serialization from pojo to bytes/string is costly and liner to size and depth of the data object. You mentioned that it is huge object so serialization will create good amount of performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Putting descriptive answer since object can not be shared due to legal reason.

You have couple of choices. Each with pro and con.

**Reflection**

You can maintain a list of fields not allowed to change with their full path. Like a.b.c. You can then write pure reflection code or use common utils like  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/ to get values (even deep in object tree) and compare.

It needs less code and less maintenance. But you need to know exact list of blacklist fields. Performance wise it will take little bit more time.

**Simple plain code technique**

Write your own comparator or method in java to go through all fields that can not change and decide. Need lot of code but very easy to maintain and performance wise best.